# Laravel. Куда можно записать информацию о последнем обновлении данных, кроме самой БД?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть функция которая должна выполняться при открытии страницы, но она должна выполняться с задержкой в 10 минут, то есть - если 300 пользователей в течении 5 минут откроют страницу, то функция должна выполнится 1 раз. А если 300 пользователей откроют страницу в течении 11 минут, то она должна выполнится 2 раза.
Куда можно записать информацию с временной меткой последнего выполнения функции?

Comment: фаил, база, оперативная память... Может вы изобретаете crontab что эта функция делает и для чего она?

Answer (score 3):

Пишите в файл на сервере, например.
Т.е. Прочитали с файла -> time()>(time_from_file()+600*****)

*****10 минут

P.S. В вашей ситуации идеально подойдет CRON